# How to get page load time with Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to get page load time with Chrome extension? 
Have Chrome extensions API something to calculate it?

Comment: [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) or read [performance.timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing) in a content script.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the developer console (F12) and check the network tab to see how long it takes to build the site.

There you can see the DOM Loading Time, Transfer Time and Total Time

Comment: No, I need to get loading time from my own extension. Can I do this with Chrome Extensions API?

Answer (score 0):

I found extension, which code I can use in my extension

https://github.com/alex-vv/chrome-load-timer

It is what I need

Comment: I find this adds significant time to the page load... I don't recommend it